# Are private HTTP events possible with Serverless?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I would like to have this architecture:
[image: serverless-architecture]

Here, the ScoringService has GET and POST endpoints. The POST endpoints may only be available for for services within the VPC (ExerciseService and QuizService). The GET endpoint of the ScoringService must be available for the client.

According to the [Serverless documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#configuring-endpoint-types), I can make the entire ScoringService private. But for this architecture, I only want the POST endpoint to be private. The GET endpoint should be accessible for the client.

So something like this:

```
service: my-service
 provider:
 name: aws
 functions:
  scoring:
   events:
    - http:
      path: score
      method: get
      endpointType: EDGE
    - http:
      path: score
      method: post
      endpointType: PRIVATE
```

But I don't think this is a valid Serverless configuration. Is the architecture above somehow possible with Serverless?

Answer (score 3):

### Private API

The purpose of the attribute `endpointType=private` is to make the entire api internal to the VPC. Therefore the property is not applicable to an endpoint.

### protected Endpoint

If you would simply like to protect an api endpoint, you can configure the api endpoint to be accessible only when an api key is provided. you can do it by setting the attribute `private` to `true`, If you do so, The api is still public accessible, but the api endpoint is protected by an `api-key`.The api key is expected to be sent in the `x-api-key` header. remember, this is different to an internal api where the api is internal to VPC and not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have private function.

So what you can do here is make ScoringService's post function private.

```
service: my-service
provider:
  name: aws
  apiKeys:
    - myFirstKey 
functions:
 getScoring:
    events:
      - http:
          path: <your-scoring-get-path>
          method: get
 postScoring:
    events:
      - http:
          path: <your-scoring-post-path>
          method: post
          private: true
```

So now clients connecting to this post Rest API will then need to set any of these API keys values in the x-api-key header of their request. This is only necessary for functions where the private property is set to true.

For more information about setting api keys for read [this](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#setting-api-keys-for-your-rest-api).